# Scheme lambda or define?

Tags: scheme

What's the difference between the two lines?
I want to make an adder function.
It turned out the first line works but the second not.
I'm new to scheme, thanks.

```
(define (make-adder num) (lambda (x) (+ num x))) 
(define (make-adder num) (define (foo x) (+ num x)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form

```
(define (name args ...)
  defines ... body ...)
```

Is just syntactic sugar for:

```
(define name 
  (lambda (args ...)
    defines ... body ...))
```

Now inside a lambda form you may zero or more local `define` then followed with at least one body expression. In your first example you have zero defines and one body expression, namely the lambda expression that turns into a closure once applied.

Your second version has one define of the local variable `foo` but since there is no body expression this is not valid Scheme code. In order to be equivalent to the first code you need to have the variable you just defined as the body, returning the newly created closure, like this:

```
(define (make-adder num)
  (define (foo x) 
    (+ num x))
  foo)
```

Now the two versions are identical. You can also write it fully out so that the Scheme implementation doesn't need to expand the sugar like this:

```
(define make-adder
  (lambda (num)
    (define foo (lambda (x) (+ num x)))
    foo))
```

Of course it doesn't hurt to use sytactic sugar, but books like The little Schemer has avoided using the short form just because it might give the impression the procedures are more than just variables that evaluate to procedure objects. eg. in `(a b c)` `a` is just a variable, just like `b` and `c`. The only difference is that there is a requirement that `a` evaluates to a procedure, just like in `(+ c d)` `c` and `d` needs to be numbers to avoid a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

`lambda` defines a function and returns it. `define` defines a value (potentially a function), but does not return it. So you're right about the equivalence of the functions defined by the two forms, but you need to return `foo` in the second:

```
(define (make-adder num)
  (define (foo x) 
    (+ num x))
  foo)
```